# Play mp3 file using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

When I use MediaPlayer to play mp3 file, the system will report error log: `Prepare failed: status=0xFFFFFF8E`. But the Realplayer is normal.

I find that it has the error occurred only in higher ROM version. Like in the version4.0 it has the error. In version2.3 it has not the error.

The code:

```
private MediaPlayer mpBack = null;
/**
 * read in background sound from the resource file 
 * @param resId
 */
public void MediaPlay(int resId){
if(!isPlaying()){
mpBack = MediaPlayer.create(ctMedia, resId);
/**Volume Set */
mpBack.setVolume(0.8f, 0.8f);   
/**Background music default infinite loop*/
mpBack.setLooping(true);    
mpBack.start();
}
}
```

LogCat error：

```
12-18 21:51:57.380: E/MediaPlayer(31457): mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.

12-18 21:51:57.380: E/MediaPlayer(31457): mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.
```

Comment: I have the very same problem, and the suggestions below don't work. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mpBack.prepare();
```

before you start mediaplayer

Comment: `MediaPlayer.create` calls `prepare` automatically. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mpBack = new MediaPlayer().create(context, R.raw.blah);
```